# JavaScript : Ordering AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 ajax call for particular functionality. 3rd call is dependent of first 2 calls i.e. for the 3 rd call first 2 calls has to be finished. But first 2 AJAX calls are independent. So I want them to be async and execute parallely.

How to structure these calls now? I tried to put them in nested success block of respective calls, but it that case first 2 calls are also not independent.

Kindly suggest with some sudo code, if possible.

Comment: Similar to this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792277/jquery-getting-rid-of-nested-ajax-functions/21792307#21792307

Comment: Read a very good article regarding parallel and series AJAX call http://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [promises](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/) and [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2()).then(ajaxCall3);
```

where `ajaxCallX` is something like

```
function ajaxCall1() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

This basically means "after both, the promise of `ajaxCall1` and the promise of `ajaxCall2` are resolved, execute the function `ajaxCall3`".

This works because the object returned by `$.ajax` (and similar methods) implements the promise interface. More information can also be found in the [`$.ajax` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

---

The responses of each Ajax call are passed to the `then` callback as arguments. You can acess them as

```
$.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2()).then(function(a1, a2) {
    // a1[0] is the response of the first call
    // a2[0] is the response of the second call
    ajaxCall3(a1[0], a2[0]);
});
```

Have a look at the `$.when` documentation for another example.

Comment: The OP probably needs the results from the first two ajax calls in order to feed into the third so perhaps you can explain how that might be accomplished when using this structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ajaxComplete to call the third event after the first two events completes execution. ajaxComplete is an callback event which is fired after each and every ajaxCalls got response. Look over this link to find how it works https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: I don't think this is useful here. `ajaxComplete` is triggered for *every* Ajax call that completed. So if you make two Ajax calls, the event is triggered twice.

Comment: @FelixKling You can look which ajax call got over with ajaxComplete. So you can definitely use this and it works.

Comment: Why would use use ajaxComplete instead of just using the success handler for the actual ajax functions you want to monitor (or use promises on the actual ajax functions)
?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am just saying that there is also some other options to do that.