# displaying the data in UI that received via ajax call

Tags: ajax

I m having 6 ajax calls on my page where i need to get data based on a query from server for each call. So, though we are getting data asynchronously from server, will the data get displayed on HTML page asynchronously or div by div in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous and it does not guarantee ordered execution. It might happen that the first request responds last, so no, it will not be in ordered sequence.

If you need ordered requests, you can nest your callbacks or use promises like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807459/javascript-ordering-ajax-calls) thread.